# Get product link

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want rating from customers by sending mail after order is completed. If customer will click link on mail for review it should redirect to same current product page of my site.

How do I do this. I override woocommerce/emails in my child theme. I have customized `customer-completed-order.php`

```
<div class="rating">
    <h2> Please Rate this product and review. </h2>
    <a href="http://animax.cf/product/happy-ninja/#reviews">
        <img src="http://animax.cf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/product-reviews.png" alt="Product Rating">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WooCommerce default **customer-complete-order.php** email template does not link the order item to corresponding product. You need to use `woocommerce_order_item_name` filter and update the item name to have link. I just tried below code and it adds the link to order item (product name). Put this code in functions.php file of your theme. Hope this helps:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_name', 'woo_order_item_with_link', 10, 3);
function woo_order_item_with_link( $item_name, $item, $bool ) {
    $url = get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ) ;
    return '<a href="'. $url .'">'. $item_name .'</a>'; 
}
```

Comment: how do i insert that product link into <a> tag of above code.

Comment: Customer complete order email will contain order items which will be added dynamically. You need to use the code I provided as it is. The $url variable applies the link to each item in order email.